# How to convert a vim regex replace command to sed or awk?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

How would one apply this command I'm using in vim to sed or awk?

`:%s/\v\n(\D)/ \1/g`

### Explanation

- `:%`: Complete buffer
- `s/`: Substitute
- `\v`: Use regex magic...I frankly still don't understand this
- `\n`: Match new line
- `(\D)`: Match 'Not a digit'. Surrounded by braces to mark it as group
- `/ \1/g`: Replace matches with space and group 1
- `/g`: Confirm replace for all occurences

**INPUT**

```
Datum   Transaktion Branche/Partner Verrechnet  Belastung   Gutschrift  Bonuspunkte
24.12.2017  "Zinsen*
Zinsperiode: vom 24.11. bis 24.12.
Zins auf EUR 23'001'011.43 vom 20.12.-20.12. EUR 121.31
Zins auf EUR 23'002'045.73 vom 21.12.-23.12. EUR 173.99
Zins auf EUR 23'006'067.38 vom 24.12.-24.12. EUR 191.33"        Ja  239.42      0.0
23.12.2017  "Acme Ent.
Lebensmittelgeschäft
"   Lebensmittelgeschäft   Ja  121.65      121.7
20.12.2017  "Restaurant Lorem ipsum
Restaurant
"   Restaurant  Ja  15.00       15.0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Datum   Transaktion Branche/Partner Verrechnet  Belastung   Gutschrift  Bonuspunkte
24.12.2017  "Zinsen* Zinsperiode: vom 24.11. bis 24.12. Zins auf EUR 23'001'011.43 vom 20.12.-20.12. EUR 121.31 Zins auf EUR 23'002'045.73 vom 21.12.-23.12. EUR 173.99 Zins auf EUR 23'006'067.38 vom 24.12.-24.12. EUR 191.33"        Ja  239.42      0.0
23.12.2017  "Acme Ent. Lebensmittelgeschäft "   Lebensmittelgeschäft    Ja  121.65      121.7
20.12.2017  "Restaurant Lorem ipsum Restaurant "    Restaurant  Ja  15.00       15.0
```

Comment: this pattern `\n(\D)` (newline followed by a digit) does not correlate with CSV semantics which considers records as separate lines with a newline as record separator. The pattern could be applied to an arbitrary text content

Comment: it'd help if you add sample input lines and expected output for clarity.. and some context for why you need awk solution if you already have a working one with vim... in any case, tools like grep/sed/awk work line by line with newline as record separator.. so you'd need use some extra logic to work across two lines.. or if gawk is available, change RS..

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hence my question: Replace new lines that don't match aka correlate with a proper tsv. The values source from a strangely formatted bank transaction export

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hence my question: Replace new lines that don't match aka correlate with a proper tsv. The values source from a strangely formatted bank transaction export (windows csv with linebreaks and rows mixed up). 


**TLDR**: You're right, my inital post is wrong. The buffer *contains* arbitrary text (mixed up tsv)

Comment: post some testable input fragment and expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks. Does that help:
*Input:* https://pastebin.com/0Z7WM2ib   

*Output:* https://pastebin.com/HWzgA5dX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** equivalent would look as follows:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", (NR==1? "" : (/^[0-9]/? ORS : OFS)), $0 }END{ print "" }' file
```

- `OFS` - output field separator (defaults to space char)
- `ORS` - output record separator

The output:

```
Datum   Transaktion Branche/Partner Verrechnet  Belastung   Gutschrift  Bonuspunkte
24.12.2017  "Zinsen* Zinsperiode: vom 24.11. bis 24.12. Zins auf EUR 23'001'011.43 vom 20.12.-20.12. EUR 121.31 Zins auf EUR 23'002'045.73 vom 21.12.-23.12. EUR 173.99 Zins auf EUR 23'006'067.38 vom 24.12.-24.12. EUR 191.33"        Ja  239.42      0.0
23.12.2017  "Acme Ent. Lebensmittelgeschäft "   Lebensmittelgeschäft    Ja  121.65      121.7
20.12.2017  "Restaurant Lorem ipsum Restaurant "    Restaurant  Ja  15.00       15.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just use vim in batch mode :) about 8 times slower, but it's an option.

```
echo '%s/blah/BLAH/ | w'|vi -e file.cfg
```

Source:
https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-as-the-poor-mans-sed/

Answer (score 1):

`sed`, `perl` solutions:

**perl**

```
tr -d '\v\n\r' < input.txt | perl -pe 's/(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})/\n\1/g'
```

**sed**

```
tr -d '\v\n\r' < input.txt | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{4\}\)/\n\1/g'
```

**Output:**

```
Datum   Transaktion Branche/Partner Verrechnet  Belastung   Gutschrift  Bonuspunkte
24.12.2017  "Zinsen* Zinsperiode: vom 24.11. bis 24.12. Zins auf EUR 23'001'011.43 vom 20.12.-20.12. EUR 121.31 Zins auf EUR 23'002'045.73 vom 21.12.-23.12. EUR 173.99 Zins auf EUR 23'006'067.38 vom 24.12.-24.12. EUR 191.33"        Ja  239.42      0.0
23.12.2017  "Acme Ent. Lebensmittelgeschäft "   Lebensmittelgeschäft    Ja  121.65      121.7
20.12.2017  "Restaurant Lorem ipsum Restaurant "    Restaurant  Ja  15.00       15.0
```

**Explanations:**

the `tr` command will remove all the `\v`, `\n`, and `\r` characters, then the `sed` command will add a new line before each date element to create your CSV structure.